# Python - Pandas delete specific rows/columns in excel

Tags: python, pandas, row, data-cleaning

i have the following excel file, and i would like to clean specific rows/columns so that i can further process the file.

[image]

I have tried this, but i have not managed to remove any of the blank lines, i ve only managed to trim from those containing data. Here, i was trying to only save the data from the third row and on.

```
xl = pd.ExcelFile("MRD.xlsx")
df = xl.parse("Sheet3")
df2 = df.iloc[3:]

writer4 = pd.ExcelWriter('pandas3.out.no3lines.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
table5 = pd.DataFrame(df2)
table5.to_excel(writer4, sheet_name='Sheet1')
writer4.save()
```

I specifically want to remove rows 1, 3 (the empty ones) and the first column, so that i can pivot it. Is there a way to do this? Thank you.

Comment: never post images of the dataset. print your dataframe instead in this case. as the empty rows will be read as NAs, you can just `df.dropna(how='all')`

Answer (score 5):

You can use `drop(...)` to remove rows, and `drop(..., axis=1)` to remove columns

```
data = [
    ['', '', '', ''],
    ['', 1, 2, 3],
    ['', '', '', ''],
    ['', 7, 8, 9],
]

import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# drop first column - [0]
df = df.drop(0, axis=1)

# drop first and third row - [0,2]
df = df.drop([0,2])

print(df)
```

Before:

```
  0  1  2  3
0           
1    1  2  3
2           
3    7  8  9
```

After:

```
   1  2  3
1  1  2  3
3  7  8  9
```

Comment: you would have to show code and full error message.

Comment: df.dropna(axis=1, how='all') this worked, your direction was right. The problem was with the NaN's and missing column name i think.