# How to remove the first column in Excel using Python

Tags: python, pandas

Now, I need to select some data from excel file and draw a chart using Python.

The first problem I come across is removing the first column in Excel which contains some useless texts. 
My code is down below:

```
import  pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel ('Kopie von Grafik_Pfahlsymposium.xlsx')
x = df.iloc[1:45, 12:13] # i need the 13th colomn and 1st-45th rows as the x value for my chart
print (x)
```

and the result in python,
what I need is only the second column which contains the important data:

```
Unnamed: 12
Alpha Ventus - AV 4      23.6885
Alpha Ventus - AV 5      15.7377
Alpha Ventus - AV11      17.3387
Amrumbank-OSS            15.9967
Borkum West 2 - BW2      7.90323
Borkum West 2 - BW4      7.94355
Borkum West 2 - BW12     10.0806
Borkum West 2 - BW15     12.9032
Borkum West 2 - BW31     10.0806
Borkum West 2 - BW34     11.2903
Borkum West 2 - BW36     9.55645
Borkum West 2 - BW41     13.3065
Borkum West 2 - BW44     10.8871
BorWin alpha             28.4339
BorWin beta                   20
BorWin gamma             21.9992
Butendiek OSS            19.6883
Dan Tysk OAP             24.1331
Dan Tysk OSS             27.3523
DolWin alpha             20.5086
DolWin gamma - B1          22.92
DolWin gamma - B2           23.6
DolWin gamma - B3           24.8
Global Tech - GT 12      11.6935
Global Tech - GT 17      12.0968
Global Tech - GT 38      14.5161
Global Tech - GT 45      12.0968
Global Tech - GT 60      14.5161
Global Tech - GT 72      21.7742
HelWin alpha - AC1         32.65
HelWin alpha - BC1            33
HelWin alpha - BC2            33
HelWin beta - No3        28.0558
HelWin beta - No6        28.0968
SylWin alpha - A1          27.44
SylWin alpha - A2         22.624
SylWin alpha - A3         27.328
SylWin alpha - B1           27.4
SylWin alpha - C1         27.368
SylWin alpha - C3         27.332
Veja Mate - VM 60        4.73077
Veja Mate - VM 61        4.52564
Veja Mate - VM 62        4.38333
Veja Mate - VM 63        4.33333
```

Some datas from the excel file:
[image: Some datas from the excel file:]

Comment: Is this not answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47498667/python-pandas-delete-specific-rows-columns-in-excel ?

Answer (score 1):

Try the using drop().

```
df = df.drop(0, axis=1)
# This should remove the first column
```

Unless you want edit the actual excel file, in which case you could just write from pandas (as of now, you've just read the file; writing would edit/replace contents in it)

Answer (score 1):

df.to_excel(export_filename, index=False, engine='xlsxwriter')